# arangodb, foxx and coffee script

Tags: json, coffeescript, arangodb

I can using foxx with coffee script, but it not working.I have a hello example application from step-by-step tutorial. I replace `app.js` by `app.coffee` (which is after compile `coffee -c app.coffee` identical with `app.js`)

In manifest.json i change extension in cotrollers

```
{
  "name": "moje",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Hello example.",
  "author": "golf",
   "controllers": {
    "/": "app.coffee"
  }
}
```

but it not working and server returns

```
 {"error":true,"code":404,"errorNum":404,"errorMessage":"unknown path 'dev/moje/hello/world'"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug. I've filed an issue: https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues/783

Comment: I tried myself and can confirm it's working now in 2.0 & devel branches.

Comment: @fceller This feature is still available in arangodb3? I found only mentions of "json" and "js" file extensions, not "coffee".

Comment: In ArangoDB 3 you have to use an external coffee-script conversion step in package.json